# What are security problems when input of internet applications are part of SQL statements?

Tags: sql, security

I am preparing for an exam in distributed systems and I'm struggling with the following question:

> You have written an internet application using html input elements for
>   the users entries. The users input is part of SQL statements. What
>   should you be aware of concerning security? Explain the solution and
>   problem. Give an example.

Is anyone familiar with this scenario and can help?

Comment: Research (i.e. google) "SQL injection attacks". Weep a little. Promise to yourself and to the world at large to only use parameter binding, even after thorough input sanitation

Comment: Makes sense! Danke für den Ansatz

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) & [What is SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/601300/1839439)

Answer (score 3):

This is a common web hacking technique called **SQL Injection**

SQL injection usually occurs when you ask a user for input, like their username/userid, and instead of a name/id, the user gives you an SQL statement that you will unknowingly run on your database.

Without protection it is possible to get usernames and passwords or delete the whole database. 
For an example see https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp

For proection you can use the following techniques:

- **1**: Use of Prepared Statements (with Parameterized Queries)
- **2**: Use of Stored Procedures
- **3**: Whitelist Input
- **4**: Escaping All User Supplied Input

For futher information see :https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html